# How to use a composite key as a foreign key? (ERROR: insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint...)

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what's the correct way to use a composite key as a foreign key. Say we have a **Country** that has many **City**s that have many **District**s. The composite key on **City** works fine without the **District** table, but when I add a **District** table and try to add a country entry (with cities and districts) I get the following error:

```
 ERROR: insert or update on table "district" violates foreign key constraint "fk_city_country"
  Detail: Key (country_id, city_id)=(city01, country01) is not present in table "city".
```

The relevant, simplified, code:

```java
// CountryEntity.java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public", name = "country")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class CountryEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
 
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private List<CityEntity> cities;
}
```

```java
// CityEntity.java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public", name = "city")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class CityEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CityKey id;
 
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private List<DistricyEntity> districts;
}
```

```java
// CityKey.java
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CityKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private String countryId;
 
    @Column(name = "district_id")
    private String districtId;
}
```

```java
// DistricyEntity.java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public", name = "district")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class DistrictEntity {
    @Id
    public String id;
 
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private String countryId;
 
    @Column(name = "city_id")
    private String cityId;
}
```

```yaml
# liquibase yaml changelog entry
- changeSet:
    id:  1
    author:  johnDoe
    changes:
      - createTable:
          tableName: country
          columns:
            - column:
                name: id
                type: varchar
                constraints:
                  nullable: false
                  primaryKey: true
      - createTable:
          tableName: city
          columns:
            - column:
                name: country_id
                type: varchar
                constraints:
                  nullable: false
                  references: country(id)
                  foreignKeyName: country_fk
            - column:
                name: city_id
                type: varchar
      - addPrimaryKey:
          columnNames: country_id, city_id
          constraintName: city_cpkey
          tableName: city
      - createTable:
          tableName: district
          columns:
            - column:
                name: id
                type: varchar
                constraints:
                  nullable: false
                  primaryKey: true
            - column:
                name: country_id
                type: varchar
            - column:
                name: city_id
                type: varchar
      - addForeignKeyConstraint:
          baseColumnNames: country_id, city_id
          baseTableName: district
          referencedColumnNames: country_id, city_id
          referencedTableName: city
          constraintName: fk_city_country
```

Comment: What is the order in which you create the entities? From your question it reads as if you create the district before country/city `but when I add a District and try to add a country (with cities and districts)`

Comment: Bad phrasing by my part. I've added a clarification. I mean that everything works fine without the District table so it seems that the composite key is defined correctly and the problem is with the foreign key that tries to reference it.

Comment: In `CityEntity` use `@JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name = "country_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "city_id") })` instead of the 2 `@JoinColumn`. AFAIK it doesn't work to just repeat the annotation to define multiple join columns

Comment: And you seem to have your columns mixed up. Your `city` table has the columns `country_id` and `district_id` as per your code, but `country_id` and `city_id` as per the liquibase yaml changelog entry. So I suggest getting that cleaned up first. As a hint - `@Embeddable` are not needed and replacing them might help you getting it all in order

Comment: Actually I've read somewhere that 2 @JoinColumns work instead of the combined one. It's the "new way"

Comment: Do you see that the column order is messed up in the error message? Define the `referencedColumnName` in the `@JoinColumn` if you want to map it this way.